# How to copy vertex weights over to the other side?

Tags: edit-mode, vertex-weights

Below is Edit Mode in which the vertex group "DEF-upper_arm.L" is selected. There are weights assigned.

I want to copy the weights over to the corresponding vertices on the other side (that is, DEF-upper_arm.R).

Is there an easy way to do that?

[image: Def-upper_arm.L is selected. How can I copy the weights over to DEF-upper_arm.R?]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the vertex group in the *Vertex Groups* list, then in the *Object Data* panel, in the dropdown menu on the right of the list, select *Copy Vertex Group* then *Mirror Vertex Group*:

[image]